# O quão úteis são as annotations em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, spring

Quando eu estudei Java pela primeira vez, quando vi sobre Annotations só vi que elas são úteis para gerar metadados, mas não vi nada que influenciasse no comportamento do programa. Basicamente, só vi Annotations para marcar autores de classes, para o que a classe foi feita, etc...

Mas lendo códigos em Java relevantes, vi muitas Annotations com usos que eu não conheço, aqui vai um exemplo de um Hello World usando Spring:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/#quick-start

Pelo que eu andei pesquisando, se bem usadas Annotations podem até mesmo serem mais flexíveis que os pré-processadores do C/C++!

Quais são as utilidades gerais das Annotations em Java?

Comment: Acho que uma propriedade fundamental das annotations é a de funcionar como fornecedoras de configuração (assim como arquivos XML) mas cujos dados podem ser validados em tempo de compilação, o que as torna mais resistentes a erros.

Comment: Eu gosto de definir *Annotations* como comentários semânticos disponíveis em *runtime*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O conceito mais básico é: **anotações são metadados**.

São dados adicionais que você relaciona com **classes, métodos, atributos, parâmetros e variáveis**.

Os dados podem ser usados em tempo de **compilação e de execução**, conforme definição da anotação.

## Pré-processamento durante a compilação

Em tempo de compilação, as anotações podem servir, por exemplo, para geração de código adicional ou até mesmo de modificação no *bytecode* da classe.

As anotações de tempo de compilação são removidas no *bytecode* e não ficam disponíveis em tempo de execução.

Vejamos algumas ideias sobre o que é possível fazer com isso.

#### Geradores e manipuladores de código

Por exemplo, o Hibernate pode adicionar métodos *wrappers* aos *getters* originais da classe para conseguir carregar os dados em modo *lazy*. Falei grego? Isso significa que se você tem as entidades entidades `Cliente` e `Conta` e chama um método `cliente.getConta()`, na verdade chamará um método substituto gerado pelo Hibernate que, no caso da conta não ter sido já lida do banco de dados, fará um `SELECT` e criará o objeto `conta` com os respectivos dados, retornando então o valor carregado.

Outro exemplo de pré-processamento é o projeto [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/). Ele é capaz de gerar as rotinas mais comuns usadas em POJOs, como *getters*, *setters*, *toString()* e *hashCode()*. Veja um exemplo, veja o que a anotação `@Data` é capaz de fazer:

```java
@Data(staticConstructor="of")
public class Company {
    private final Person founder;
    private String name;
    private List<Person> employees;
}
```

O código acima é equivalente ao seguinte:

```java
public class Company {
    private final Person founder;
    private String name;
    private List<Person> employees;

    private Company(final Person founder) {
        this.founder = founder;
    }

    public static Company of(final Person founder) {
        return new Company(founder);
    }

    public Person getFounder() {
        return founder;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Person> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(final List<Person> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    public boolean equals(final java.lang.Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true;
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (o.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
        final Company other = (Company)o;
        if (this.founder == null ? other.founder != null : !this.founder.equals(other.founder)) return false;
        if (this.name == null ? other.name != null : !this.name.equals(other.name)) return false;
        if (this.employees == null ? other.employees != null : !this.employees.equals(other.employees)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int PRIME = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = result * PRIME + (this.founder == null ? 0 : this.founder.hashCode());
        result = result * PRIME + (this.name == null ? 0 : this.name.hashCode());
        result = result * PRIME + (this.employees == null ? 0 : this.employees.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    public java.lang.String toString() {
        return "Company(founder=" + founder + ", name=" + name + ", employees=" + employees + ")";
    }
}
```

#### Ajuda ao desenvolvedor

Além disso, as anotações podem ser usadas para certos tipos de validação na compilação. Tome por exemplo a anotação `@Override`. Ela define que um método da subclasse está sobrescrevendo um método da superclasse. Aparentemente isso não ajuda em nada... até que alguém altere a assinatura do método na superclasse. Se alguém alterar o método na superclasse o seu método da subclasse passaria a ser um método diferente. Nesse caso, o compilador vai avisar que o seu método com `@Override` não está está sobrescrevendo mais nada! Isso ajuda muito a detectar problemas, por exemplo, ao atualizar uma biblioteca.

#### O céu é o limite

Outras ferramentas geram arquivos de configuração baseados nas anotações para melhorar o desempenho no tempo de execução.

Enfim, você mesmo pode fazer o seu processador de anotações para rodar na compilação de um programa e gerar o que você quiser, basta usar a API [APT (Annotation Processing Tool)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/), disponível desde o Java. Veja um [artigo](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17876.html) sobre o assunto (em Inglês).

## Inspeção em tempo de execução

Já as anotações que são mantidas em tempo de execução podem ser usadas por bibliotecas e frameworks para identificar os elementos e executar anotações adicionais.

#### Configuração automática

No caso do Spring, por exemplo, você deve ter visto que pode anotar a classe da seguinte forma:

```java
@Component
public class MessagePrinter { ... }
```

Qual é a mágica aqui? Quando o Spring for iniciado através do *listener* no seu `web.xml`, ele vai ler todas as classes dentro do(s) pacote(s) configurado(s) e adicionar à lista de componentes gerenciados sempre que encontrar uma anotação como essa.

Aí você não precisa mais daqueles XMLs gigantescos que precisavam ser atualizados sempre que você mudava uma classe de pacote ou a renomeava.

Para mais detalhes sobre o Spring, leia meu artigo *[Quais anotações usar nos componentes do Spring 3](http://luizricardo.org/2014/03/quais-anotacoes-usar-nos-componentes-do-spring-3/)*.

#### Injeção de Dependências

Além disso, uma anotação como `@Autowired` permite a você especificar ao Spring que aquele atributo deve ser preenchido com algum componente daquele tipo. Exemplo:

```java
@Autowired ClienteDAO clienteDAO;
```

Pronto. Sem XML, sem frescura. Se existir uma classe `ClienteDAO` com uma anotação do Spring, ele vai automaticamente criar uma instância dela e atribuir ali!

#### Formatação automática

Muitos frameworks fazem a mágica de enviar e recuperar dados automaticamente de formulários HTML, bancos de dados, arquivos, etc. Isso é bem legal, mas como especificar o formato dos dados? Lembrando que, por exemplo, um atributo de data pode ter diferentes representações num mesmo conjunto de dados.

Por exemplo, no JPA é possível especificar se o campo com um `Date` deve salvar apenas a data ou o horário também:

```java
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="CAMPO_DATA")
public Date getData()
```

Sem isso, você teria que escrever código ou configuração num arquivo.

No Spring, você pode usar a anotação [`@DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) para definir qual o formato da data quando este for convertido de e para uma String. Assim o Spring pode automaticamente receber os dados submetidos de um formulário HTML e convertê-los adequadamente para os tipos de uma classe.

#### Ao infinito e além

Mais uma vez, o limite para o uso de anotações em tempo de execução é proporcional à criatividade do desenvolvedor.

## Considerações

O maior cuidado que todo desenvolvedor precisa ter, em minha experiência, é atentar para o fato de que as anotações são "estáticas". Isso significa que se um determinado elemento anotado pode ter uma função em um momento e outra função em outro momento, talvez seja o caso de usar uma configuração externa.

Só para citar um exemplo, se você usou anotações para configurar Injeção de Dependências com `@Autorired` e depois decidiu mudar o objeto injetado por uma subclasse, vai precisar recompilar o código adicionando um `@Qualifier`. Com a configuração em XML, você não precisaria disso. Então, existem alguns casos onde a configuração por XML dá uma maior flexibilidade para o gerenciamento da aplicação fora do ambiente de desenvolvimento.

De qualquer forma, as anotações são um recurso extremamente poderoso e flexível da plataforma Java. Elas são metadados que podem ser lidos por frameworks e bibliotecas em detrimento de configuração via XML e programação imperativa.

Answer (score 2):

Annotations é uma ferramenta poderosa, e o seu maior poder é poder "configurar" objetos sem a necessidade de se conhecer o conteúdo e formação da classe.

Vou usar o exemplo classico em explicação de Annotation (pelo menos eu uso sempre esse).

Quando usamos a JTable temos que configurar um tableModel, o default é horrível então geralmente criamos um para cada tabela que vamos apresentar, certo?

Com Annotations podemos criar um configurador do tableModel sem a necessidade de conhecer durante sua criação, campos, objetos ou coisas que precisamos colocar nele.

Criamos assim um tableModelGenerico que através de reflection ele vai procurar em uma classe indicada o que ele deve considerar como colunas, até mesmo tamanho dos campos, formatação, cores, etc.

Ex.

Criei minha classe

```
Classe {

  private int ID;
  @TableLineCor(GREEN)
  @Coluna(Nome='Nome')
  private String Nome;

  @Coluna(Nome='Data de Nascimento')
  private Date Data;

//gets and sets.

}
```

Então o que aconteceu aqui, quando o seu tableModelGenerico receber como parametro essa classe e através de reflection ele ler já saberá que receberá uma lista de objetos dessa classe, onde a linha tem que ser verde, que terá uma coluna chamada Nome que receberá os dados da propriedade Nome e que terá outra coluna chamada Data de Nascimento e que receberá os dados da propriedade Data.

Então dessa forma, as Annotations permitiram que você consiga criar algo muito genérico e que não precisará ser reescrito quando algo mudar no cenário.

Acredito que essa seja uma das funções mais importantes das Annotations.

Comment: Apenas um comentário sobre o que eu coloquei, cores foi apenas um exemplo porque pensando bem não funcionaria exaaaatamente dessa forma, pois quem define a parte de cores é um handle na JTable e não no Model.

Answer (score 1):

Só pra complementar as outras respostas, acho que posso dar um bom exemplo prático que ajuda a entender algumas coisas explicadas acima:

Como já sabemos, uma das utilidades das anotações é ajudar a diminuir algumas configurações. O exemplo que me vem a cabeça foi quando a especificação dos Servlets foi alterada com o lançamento do Java EE 6 ([JSF315](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html)). Antes da versão 3.0, era tudo mapeado dentro do web.xml, e na nova especificação, apenas com uma anotação, tudo é resolvido internamente.

3.0

```
@WebServlet(value="/oiMundo")
public class OiMundo extends HttpServlet {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

2.5

```
<servlet>
   <display-name>Servlet1</display-name>
   <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>test.Servlet1</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>sleep-time-in-seconds</param-name>
     <param-value>10</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/Servlet1</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```