# Qual a diferença entre JavaBean e POJO?

Tags: java, java-bean, pojo

Sou novo na linguagem java e tenho essa dúvida. Procurei em vários locais na internet e perguntei a vários amigos programadores JAVA mas nenhum conseguiu me explicar com clareza qual a diferença entre os dois.

Qual a diferença entre JavaBean e POJO?

Comment: Possível resposta para a pergunta sobre [beans](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/o-que-%C3%A9-e-para-que-serve-um-java-bean) e sobre [pojo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17499/o-qu%C3%A3o-%C3%BAteis-s%C3%A3o-as-annotations-em-java/17531#17531)

Comment: @Caputo A parte do JavaBean, creio que a pergunta linkada atende. Mas não me parece haver referência para POJO aqui no SOpt, por isso creio que a pergunta deve ser mantida.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Concordo sim e inclusive para existir uma relação entre eles a pergunta é válida. Só adicionei os links porque estava sem tempo de responder e poderia ajudar o OP enquanto respostas não surgem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[POJO - *Plain Old Java Object*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Objects) - é simplesmente uma denominação que se dá para um objeto "normal", sem nada de especial. Ele tem seus campos, seus métodos, seus construtores, etc, mas não segue [necessariamente] nenhum padrão pré-estabelecido.

À medida que a linguagem Java foi evoluindo, foram surgindo ferramentas automatizadas para se fazer interface com seu código de forma declarativa e/ou visual, sem a necessidade de escrever código manualmente. Muitas vezes essas ferramentas exigiam - para realizar sua função - que as classes envolvidas estivessem escritas de uma forma bem específica, caso contrário elas não seriam compatíveis com essas ferramentas.

Um exemplo são os JavaBeans, que na época que eu estudei tinham como objetivo facilitar a criação de interfaces gráficas de usuário (não sei como é hoje, nem se esse objetivo foi pra frente - pois não trabalho mais com Java há anos). Um JavaBean precisa de, das duas uma:

1. Seguir uma convenção bem rígida, incluindo um construtor sem parâmetros e métodos para se obter e atribuir valores aos seus campos ("getters e setters") com um padrão de nomenclatura e assinatura (i.e. número e tipos dos parâmetros e valor de retorno);
2. Usar uma classe auxiliar - BeanDescriptor ou algo assim - para descrever a estrutura da classe às ferramentas que trabalham com Beans, caso não fosse possível usar a convenção acima. (o que "mata" boa parte das vantagens de se trabalhar com beans)

Outro formato são os EJB - Enterprise JavaBeans - nesse caso focados numa [arquitetura orientada por serviço (SOA)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture), se não me engano. E sempre que surgia uma ferramenta nova - por exemplo, para fazer o mapeamento objeto-relacional - era comum se exigir um padrão diferente, por vezes conflitante.

Diante dessa multiplicidade de padrões, e dos problemas que isso acarretava, passou-se a tentar tornar as ferramentas que lidam com código flexíveis o bastante para aceitar qualquer formato, independentemente de padrão. Na falta de um nome próprio para descrever essa característica, cunhou-se o termo POJO, para expressar a ideia que "pra minha ferramenta tratar da sua classe não precisa dela ter nada especial, um objeto simples qualquer serve".

Por essa razão, dizer que qualquer objeto é um POJO (por exemplo, todo JavaBean é um POJO, mas nem todo POJO é um JavaBean) embora tecnicamente correto não quer dizer muita coisa... Por outro lado, dizer que a ferramenta X trata de POJOs fala muito sobre a flexibilidade dessa ferramenta: pois não importa em que formato suas classes estão, ela afirma ser capaz de lidar com elas. É sob essa ótica que você deve interpretar o termo "POJO", sempre que o vir.

Comment: Resposta excelente! Consegui entender. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Exato! Infelizmente ocorre muita confusão porque o termo *bean* é extremamente sobrecarregado na plataforma Java. Inclusive alguns frameworks também se apropriaram do termo. Temos o JSF com os *managed beans*, os *Spring beans* e por aí vai. Algumas vezes as pessoas usam o termo *bean* para tudo, então a confusão só piora. Por exemplo, imagine explicar um cenário onde um *managed bean* chama um *enterprise java bean* ou *spring bean*, passando como argumento um *POJO* que contém anotações *bean validation*.

Comment: É, esse povo querendo fazer trocadilho com tudo... Java Bean, Ruby Gem, Python Egg...

Comment: @mgibsonbr nunca tinha entendido o Python Egg ou Ruby Gem até agora! Cocoa pod também é trocadilho?