# O que são classes pré-especificadas?

Tags: java, classes, pojo

Lendo a publicação na wikipedia sobre POJO (Plain Old Java Objects), me deparei com o termo classes pré-especificadas. Entendi muito superficialmente que talvez se trate das classes da especificação, mas não ficou muito claro.

Poderiam explicar melhor?

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Objects

> **Definição**
>
> Falando idealmente, um POJO é um objeto de Java não limitado por
> alguma restrição outra que esses forçados por Java Language
> Specification. Em outras palavras, um POJO deve:
>
> Não estender classes pre-especificadas, como em public class Foo
> extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet { ... Não implementar
> interfaces pre-especificadas, como em public class Bar implements
> javax.ejb.EntityBean { ... Não conter anotações pre-especificadas,
> como em @javax.persistence.Entity public class Baz { ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesse caso esse termo fica um pouco esquisito ou sem dar contexto, mas é simples. Fica mais fácil se estivesse escrito "previamente declaradas" ou "já criadas"? Esta última até flerta coo o erro, mas parece que deixa mais óbvio o que é. Ou seja, está falando apenas sobre classes já existentes no código.

Mas tem uma ressalva: toda classe Java herda de pelo menos a classe `Object`, essa não é contada nesta restrição. Isso ocorre por causa da especificação da linguagem forçar todas classes ter uma raiz comum. O texto é um pouco mal escrito e não deixa isso tão claro.

Classes POJO são simples, e fogem um pouco do que se convenciona usa em orientação a objeto, elas não tem herança, mecanismos sofisticados, ou até comportamentos além dos triviais do objeto, mas nada que crie mecanismos extras de manipulação do objeto, como é comum.

Comment: certo, acho que estou entendo, mas como assim préviamente declaradas ou já criadas. Em algum momento eu vou criar a classe que quero herdar, não?

Comment: Sim, sem criar algo, não existe e o que não existe não pode ser usado.

Comment: Ok, então a conclusão é, POJOs não herdam (extends, implements ou recebam annotatios) de forma alguma (exceto a objects)?

Então o texto da Wikipédia está meio confuso e pra mim, deu ao intender que é possível aplicar herança exceto nesses casos com classes pre-especificadas.

Comment: Nesse ponto não está confuso, está em outros.

Comment: Entendi melhor agora, depois de ler Deitel

Answer (score 1):

A questão das classes pré-especificadas é o seguinte.

Plain Old Java Objects significa mais ou menos "Os bons e velhos objetos Java". Significa um objeto Java puramente criado por você, usando no máximo bibliotecas já inclusas do Java, criado sem nenhum tipo de particularidade de frameworks externos, como o framework de Servlets ou de JEE (EJB), que são tecnologias posteriores à JDK que obrigam os objetos Java a terem "particularidades" na sua declaração/implementação, como por exemplo implementar uma interface ou estender uma classe específica do framework, que é o que o texto chama de "classe pré-estabelecida", ou ter determinadas anotações, com a intenção de rodar em um *Container*. POJOs poderiam ser chamados de *"[Vanilla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/357) Java Objects"* que teria o mesmo efeito.

[Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22615/357) explica bem o que são.

Eu não mexi com JEE e não lembro exatamente como é um Enterprise Java Bean, mas o Fowler e colegas quiseram mostrar na palestra que dava para programar sem precisar de EJB, só com objetos comuns, e chamou esses objetos comuns (não-EJB) de POJO, como ele conta [aqui](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/POJO.html).

Um objeto de domínio, como um `Pedido` ou um `Cliente` é um POJO típico. Um JavaBean é um POJO com certas particularidades, mas que não depende de nada externo, portanto ainda é um POJO.

Um EJB, um Servlet e uma entidade do Hibernate não são POJOs, implementam interfaces específicas externas à JDK, anotações específicas.

Um DAO ou Repository que use Hibernate eu não sei se é POJO. Uma subclasse de um componente Java Swing eu não sei se é POJO. Mas pode ser sexo dos anjos e não sei se vale a pena ficar discutindo. O termo POJO surgiu como uma reação aos EJBs do Java EE, e é isso que ele é, um objeto comum que não precisa ser um EJB.